# Paths in the hyperbolic disk

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, fundamental-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $\Gamma \le \operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ be a discrete subgroup and $\Sigma:=\mathbb{D}^2/\Gamma$ be the quotient. Then $\Sigma$ is a hyperbolic surface whose universal cover is $\mathbb{D}^2$ and the fundamental group $\pi_1(\Sigma,x)$ ($x\in\Sigma$) is isomorphic to $\Gamma$. Fix a point $\tilde{x}\in\mathbb{D}^2$ over $x$.

For two loops $\alpha, \beta:S^1(\cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \Sigma$ in $\pi_1(\Sigma,x)$
(so $\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=\beta(0)=\beta(1)=x$), let

$\tilde{\alpha}_0, \tilde{\beta}_0:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}^2$ be the liftings of $\alpha, \beta$, respectively, with $\tilde{\alpha}_0(0)=\tilde{\beta}_0(0)=\tilde{x}$.

Then let

$\tilde{\alpha}_1:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}^2$ be the lifting of $\alpha$ with $\tilde{\alpha}_1(0)=\tilde{\beta}_0(1)$,

and

$\tilde{\beta}_1:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}^2$ the lifting of $\beta$ with $\tilde{\beta}_1(0)=\tilde{\alpha}_0(1)$.

[image]

Now I want to show that $\tilde{\alpha}_0$, $\tilde{\beta}_0$, $
\tilde{\alpha}_1$ and $\tilde{\beta}_1$ don't make an embedded quadrangle in $\mathbb{D}^2$. Can I show this using techniques in hyperbolic geometry or find some counterexamples? Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: I presume that by a "loop in $\pi_1(\Sigma,x_0)$" you mean just a continuous function $[0,1] \mapsto \Sigma$ with endpoints $0,1$ mapped to $x_0$? And I presume that by the statement "$\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$ never meet in $\mathbb H$" you mean that $\text{image}(\alpha_1) \cap \text{image}(\beta_1) = \emptyset$? If so then what you want to show is very false; in fact for any $\alpha,\beta$ you can replace $\beta$ by another loop in the same path homotopy class which makes that statement false.

Comment: @LeeMosher I understood what you meant. Thank you very much! So I edited my question so that four curves don't make a rectangle, which was my original curiosity. In this case, I think the deforming process doesn't immediately give a counterexample.

Comment: @LeeMosher I realized that your method also works for finding a counterexample on the edited question. I posted it as my own answer. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to add more assumptions, e.g. that your loops are periodic geodesics.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, indeed. Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to show it with Gauss-Bonnet theorem, but just found that is not at least trivial. So I posted it as a separate question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4887099/geodesics-in-hyperbolic-disk. It would be great if you are interested in it.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile I found a counterexample on my own on a punctured torus,
using @LeeMosher 's comment.
[image]