# Geodesics in Hyperbolic Disk

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Let $\Gamma \le \operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ be a discrete subgroup and $\Sigma:=\mathbb{D}^2/\Gamma$ be the quotient. Then $\Sigma$ is a hyperbolic surface whose universal cover is $\mathbb{D}^2$ and the fundamental group $\pi_1(\Sigma,x)$ ($x\in\Sigma$) is isomorphic to $\Gamma$. Fix a point $\tilde{x}\in\mathbb{D}^2$ over $x$.

For two closed geodesics $\alpha, \beta:S^1(\cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \Sigma$,
which are elements of $\pi_1(\Sigma,x)$
(so $\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=\beta(0)=\beta(1)=x$), let

> $\tilde{\alpha}_0, \tilde{\beta}_0:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}^2$ be the liftings of $\alpha, \beta$, respectively, with $\tilde{\alpha}_0(0)=\tilde{\beta}_0(0)=\tilde{x}$.

Then let

> $\tilde{\alpha}_1:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}^2$ be the lifting of $\alpha$ with $\tilde{\alpha}_1(0)=\tilde{\beta}_0(1)$,

and

> $\tilde{\beta}_1:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}^2$ the lifting of $\beta$ with $\tilde{\beta}_1(0)=\tilde{\alpha}_0(1)$.

[image]

My claim is that

> $\tilde{\alpha}_0$, $\tilde{\beta}_0$, $
> \tilde{\alpha}_1$ and $\tilde{\beta}_1$ do not make an embedded quadrangle in $\mathbb{D}^2$.

In the case the loops are not assumed to be geodesics,
I already know that there are counterexamples,
see [Paths in the hyperbolic disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4885634/paths-in-the-hyperbolic-disk?noredirect=1#comment10422872_4885634).

I tried prove the claim with geodesics (or minimally meeting curves) with Gauss-Bonnet theorem, but it gave me only a restriction between angles.
Can I show this using another techniques in hyperbolic geometry or find some counterexamples? Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is positive but I do not know an elementary proof (I also do not have a reference). The nonelementary proof uses the fact that for the one-punctured torus every outer automorphism of the fundamental group is induced by a self-homeomorphism of the punctured torus.